# Java Netbeans 8.2 Debugging: Error: Could not find or load main class some.main.Class

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I am trying to debug a java file in netbeans 8.2 and I am getting this error. I have seen posts on netbeans 8.0 that show where to set the main class but it has moved in 8.2. Can someone point me to what I need to change to allow debugging in netbeans 8.2

Under the categories menu there should be a run option to make this setting but I do not see a run option.

[image]

There is run listed under the categories menu, however, there is no setting for main class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off...does the file you're trying to run contain a **main()** method? If not then there must be a class that does. You can select which Class will be considered the Startup Class by doing this:

1. With you mouse pointer, select the Project Name within the Projects
   pane typically located on the left side of the NetBeans IDE;
2. Right-Click on the Project Name and from the popup menu select
   **Properties**;
3. From the displayed Project Properties windows select **Run** from
   the **Categories** pane;
4. On the right side of the Project Properties window you will notice a
   label stating: **Main Class**. The Class which is considered the
   Startup Class is displayed within the Text Field. Select the
   **Browse** button located at the far right and then select your desired startup class from the **Main Classes** popup dialog window;
5. After selecting your desired startup Main Class select the **Select
   Main Class** button to close the popup dialog then select the **OK**
   button located at the bottom of the Project Properties window;
6. Done. Run your application.

Comment: Thank you for for these steps as they are very clear. However, I do not have a Run option under categories. I will post a picture in the question.